# How to connect MS Access 2016 to SQL Server 2017 where SQL Server is installed on Linux?

Tags: ms-access-2016, sql-server-2017

I am on a Windows 10 machine with MS Access 2016 trying to connect to SQL Server 2017 on Centos 7 Linux. I have an SSH connection via Putty. I tried creating a DSN alone first, but didn't have any luck. I don't see any examples on how to setup a DSN for SQL Server 2017.

Here is the error I get when trying to connect the ODBC connector:

> Microsoft SQL Server Login
>
> Connection failed:
>   SQLState: '08001'
>   SQL Server Error: 2
>   [Microsoft][OD8C Driver 13 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: 
>   Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].
>   Connection failed:
>   SQLState: 'HYTOO'
>   SQL Server Error: O
>   [Microsoft][OD8C Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired

Comment: Office x86? You use ODBC 32 Bit? TCP/IP is on https://serverfault.com/questions/82007/how-do-i-get-this-sql-server-odbc-connection-working?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @Joe Bigler  Did you resolve this?  Is the issue the SSH connection or is it because SQL Server 2017 is not compatible with MS Access 2016?